Showing $\frac{\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r\;^nC_r\;\left(\frac{1}{r+p+1}\right)}{\sum_{r=0}^p (-1)^r\;^pC_r\;\left(\frac{1}{r+n+1}\right)}=1$
Show that the following expression simplifies to $1$:

$$\frac{ \sum\limits_{r=0}^n (-1)^r\cdot \;^nC_r\;\left(\dfrac{1}{r+p+1}\right) }{ \sum\limits_{r=0}^p (-1)^r \cdot \;\;^pC_r\;\left(\dfrac{1}{r+n+1}\right) }$$

I tried putting $p=n+a$, hoping the things cancel out somehow, but that didn't go anywhere. I've looked up solutions, but they involve integrals. How does one do this algebraically? This happens to be a problems from the JEE Advanced Exam.

Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

On top of what Blue mentioned, it's also helpful if you can give context for the problem. DId you find it in a book? In a competition? DId you make it up on your own? etc. This is mainly because one can tailor their responses likewise. For example, if it is homework and you are genuinely stuck, we can give hints to push you towards a solution.

Show that the numerator (resp denominator) is $\frac{ n!p!}{(n+p+1)!}$, hence the expression is equal to 1. $\quad$ While integration is the most direct approach (esp given the fraction), we could also prove this via induction having known the formula.

Here's hints for you to try doing it in a combinatorial way. Let's handle the sum in the numerator, the denominator can be done similarly.
The alternating sum hints at counting something using something inclusion-exclusion. But what do we count exactly?
Note that we have a $\binom{n}{r}$, so we have to somehow choose $n$ items out of $r$ items. So say we have $n$ students, and we choose $r$ of them. That gives this term. What about the $r+p+1$ factor then? Here's where the trick comes. Say you also have $p$ executives and $1$ teacher. In how many ways can you arrange all $n+p+1$ people such that all the $p$ executives and exactly $r$ students appear before the teacher? (Use stars and bars or some other method).
Once you have this, note that there are $\binom{n}{r}$ ways of selecting those $r$ students. Now use inclusion exclusion to find the number of ways you can arrange all $n+r+1$ people so that the teacher comes before everyone else, then the students and then the executives.
But this count can also be done directly, and this comes out to just $n!p!$. Equate them and you get an expression.
Finally, show that the denominator is also the same using the same method and conclude.
